# How to check if some text within some tag is visible on the webpage using javascript or react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new to programming and want to check if the h3 tag with text "hello" is present in the document.

consider the html below,

```
<div class= "parent_div">
    <div class="child_div">
        <h3>hello</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

now i want to check if the h3 element within parent_div class exists in the document that i am currently viewing. how can i do that using javascript.

i have tried using document.querySelector("div.parent_div h3[text()="hello"]")

this does not work. how can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: if you are using reactjs use the state object for this kind of stuff don't use queryselector

Comment: Totally agree with @Pardeep if you are using react use react state

Comment: Invoking the orientation on [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here: why would you like to do that? What is the problem that you would like to solve? Especially in the react case?

Comment: i have to expand the side panel (which can close and open) based on state named "expanded" being true. this gets true when the image is loaded.  Now i dont want this side panel to expand if this element that i asked in the question is seen...i dont have a state to keep track of this element. so i thought it would be good to use queryselector.

Comment: @someuser2491 I agree with everybody that in react's case you shouldn't use queryselector for that. You probably shouldn't use it even in vanilla js' case: a better way could be to implement an [observer pattern](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-design-patterns-observer-pattern/) make the code responsible for the image to notify that it was loaded and then make the code responsible for the drawer respond accordingly. In any case, I posted an answer for the react case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, in the case of React, if you don't want a side panel (or [drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/)) to be expandable until an image loads, you can use the [`onload` event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) callback to set the state of your drawer to expandable only after it loads.

```js
class Drawer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expandable: props.expandable,
      expanded: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const expandButton = (
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded })}>
        {this.state.expanded ? "Click to close..." : "Click to expand!"}
      </button>
    );

    const drawerContent = this.state.expanded ? (
      <p>I'm expanded!</p>
    ) : (
      <p>I'm not expanded :( </p>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        {expandButton}
        {drawerContent}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      drawerExpandable: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Drawer expandable={this.state.drawerExpandable} />
        <img
          src={"https://placekitten.com/200/300"}
          onLoad={() => this.setState({ drawerExpandable: true })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. actually the case is slightly complicated than this...my question is now consider i have a third component that renders onclicking a button say "click to show". now when user clicks this button "click to show" another content say "panel should be closed when i am rendered" should be shown to user. when this is rendered even though the image is downloaded the panel shouldnt be shown.  Only when i close the  content "panel should be closed when i am rendered" the panel should be expanded. this is how i needed it to work.

Comment: @someuser2491 could you please describe that problem and what have you tried in the question then?

Comment: i have found the answer to my question i used another condition to update side_panel_open state when this dialogue is open.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an approach using vanilla js:

```js
const checkExist = document.querySelector(".parent_div .child_div h3").innerText == "hello"
console.log(checkExist)
```

```html
<div class= "parent_div">
    <div class="child_div">
        <h3>hello</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

But if you are using React.js better use component state.

Comment: thanks but if the element is not present it gives error. so there shouldbe somekind of check i think

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class= "parent_div">
    <div class="child_div">
        <h3>hello</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var h3=document.getElementsByTagName('h3');
    alert(h3.length===0?'not exist':'exists, and text is :'+h3[0].innerHTML);
</script>
```